# How to select n points from a given set C (a container) such that the minimal distance between any pair of points is maximized

Tags: algorithm, optimization, distance, packing, tabu-search

Mathematically this would break down to the following problem:

max d

st (x<sub>i</sub> - x<sub>j</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>i</sub> - y<sub>j</sub>)<sup>2</sup> >= d<sup>2</sup> for 1<=i<=j<=n

(x<sub>i</sub>,y<sub>i</sub>) ∈ C for 1<=i<=n

Here, C is a closed subset of the unit square [0,1]x[0,1] with area > 0.5.

I guess this is some general formulation of a packing problem? The interior of C is then non-empty and connected and not necessarily convex. Would it be possible to solve this using a metaheuristic search method like tabusearch? Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a version of the [facility location problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location_problem)

Comment: If C is "nice" (a circle or square, for example) then in the limit as C/n goes to infinity, the best solution would be a hexagonal packing of circles.  So that's probably still a good heuristic.